# How to increase the logo image quality for pdf invoices in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

I would like to increase the quality of the logo in the PDF invoices. At the moment I upload a logo exactly 200x50 px in size and with JPG quality 99 and it still looks terrible. I also tried PNG24 without any better results. If I upload a larger logo, it is embedded larger but the quality is still shit.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I'm familiar with PHP and coding, if that is what it takes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to increasing the image quality is to keep the image uploaded at the same ratio of 200x50px, but at a higher resolution, so a 400x100px image will look better, or a 600x150px image, etc.

I've found if you don't keep the same ratio as the settings it will make the image quality look terrible.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I also changed the maximum height in the file app/code/core/mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php to prevent the logo from being too big.

Comment: 400x100px image will look better,  but it looks big. I tried with the ratio: 900x100. OK better